# symfony sfValidatorSchemaCompare and dateformat output problem

Tags: php, symfony1

```
public function configure()
  {
    $this->widgetSchema['start_date'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();
    $this->widgetSchema['end_date'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();


    $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator( new sfValidatorOr ( array( 
                                                    new sfValidatorAnd( array
                                                          (new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('start_date', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::NOT_EQUAL, null), 
                                                           new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('end_date', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, null)
                                                    )), 
                                                    new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('start_date', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::LESS_THAN_EQUAL, 'end_date', 
                                                    array('throw_global_error' => false), array('invalid' => 'The start date ("%left_field%") must be before the end date ("%right_field%")')))));
  }
```

I've got following input dates which I want to check if the end date isn't before the start date:

Input: Start => 31/03/10 End=> 07/03/10
Output: The start date (2010-03-31) must be before the end date (2010-03-07)

Can you in some way change the date output? I need the error message to set the date format the same as the input.
Also my input fields are set with the wrong date format when the error appears.

Tried several things, but no luck at this moment. Didn't find a solution or information on symfony it self.

I'm using symfony version 1.2.11

Comment: Given that you're dealing with input strings, might be easier to check this in your action after the form post, and throw an error from there or force the values, as needed. Perhaps someone else has a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a the solution together with a colleague.

After some tryouts, we found the solution to my initial problem. Instead of using that post validator, we wrote are own validator.

```
class StartBeforeEndDateValidator extends sfValidatorBase {

  public function configure($options = array(), $messages = array()) {
    parent::configure($options, $messages);
    $this->addMessage('Invalid_daterange', 'Start date (%start%) must be before End date (%end%)!');
  }

  public function doClean($values) {

    sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers('Date');

    $timestampStart = sfContext::getInstance()->getI18N()->getTimestampForCulture($values['start_date'], sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getCulture());
    $timestampEnd = sfContext::getInstance()->getI18N()->getTimestampForCulture($values['end_date'], sfContext::getInstance()->getUser()->getCulture());

    if(format_date($timestampStart) > format_date($timestampEnd)){
      throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'Invalid_daterange', array('start' => $values['start_date'], 'end' => $values['end_date']));
    }

  }

}
```

Usage of the validator in the symfony form:

```
  public function configure() {
    $this->widgetSchema['start_date'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();
    $this->widgetSchema['end_date'] = clone $this->widgetSchema['start_date'];

    $this->validatorSchema['start_date'] = new DateValidator();
    $this->validatorSchema['end_date'] = clone $this->validatorSchema['start_date'];

    $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new StartBeforeEndDateValidator());
  }
```

This was the solution to have always the same date format when it's being validated and when the validation is trigger with an error, the format of the date is correctly returned in the same date format as it was set.

Now one other "problem" that we encountered was when the save happened, the date format wasn't right for mysql. So we override the save function in our symfony form and apply the right date format.

example:

```
  public function save($con = null){

    $var = new Object();

    if($this->taintedValues['id']!= ""){
      $var->setId($this->taintedValues['id']);
    }
    $var->setStartDate(DateUtils::getIsoDateForCulture($this->taintedValues['start_date']));
    $var->setEndDate(DateUtils::getIsoDateForCulture($this->taintedValues['end_date']));
    $var->setIcpm($this->taintedValues['icpm']);

    $var->save($con);

  }
```

So once the validation is valid, it will perform the save function and set the right date format before actually save it into the database.

Hope that this is helpful for other people who had this problem.